# book count per author for filtered book list in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, aggregate

Short question.
I have two models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

One view:

```
def filter_books(request):
    book_list = Book.objects.filter(...)
```

How can I display in template next content:

```
Authors in selected books:
    Author1: book_count
    Author2: book_count
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's build the query step by step.

First, get the authors who have a book in `book_list`.

```
authors = Author.objects.filter(book__in=book_list)
```

The trick is to realise that an author will appear once for each book in `book_list`. We can then use annotate to count the number of times the author appears.

```
# remember to import Count!
from django.db.models import Count

authors = Author.objects.filter(book__in=book_list
          ).annotate(num_books=Count('id')
```

In the template, you can then do:

```
Authors in selected books:
{% for author in authors %}
{{ author.name }}: {{ author.num_books }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#first way
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='bookauthor_sets')
```

Use it directly from template:

```
{{ author.bookauthor_sets.all.count }}
```

means

author.bookauthor_sets.all().count() #with python

You can also do like this:

```
#second one
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def get_books_count(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(author=self).count()
```

In the template:

```
{{ author.get_books_count }}
```

I hope this information should help.

Comment: That's not quite what the OP has asked for: `author.get_books_count()` returns the total number of books the author has. The OP wants the number of *selected* books by the author.

Comment: Oh, i see. I might be misunderstand.