# how to display the names of all books by a particular author in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

The following code gives the number of books by a particular author with help of **.count()** present at the end.

So my query is what should I replace **.count()** in the following code with,,to get the names/titles of all the books written by a particular author

models.py::

```
class author(models.Model):
  def get_books_count(self):
      return book.objects.filter(author=self).count()
```

my query arises after seeing question on this link below::

[book count per author for filtered book list in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927251/book-count-per-author-for-filtered-book-list-in-django/49802597)

Comment: Why do you think you need to replace it with anything? Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use values_list on queryset assuming name is field in books model for book title:

```
book.objects.filter(author=self.author_name).values_list('name',flat=True)
```